# How to match the string values of 2 arrays when the other array has a Number(value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iterable

I'm new to Javascript. I'm trying to get the Math.max(...arr1[i][1]) of the array(arr1), only when it is matched with the 2nd array(arr2). Then, push it on the array(arr3) and the result should have no duplicate values.

I tried iterating both arrays(arr1 & arr2) then used an "if statement" for matching them.

```
var arr1 = [ [ 'abandon', -2 ],
[ 'abandon', 1 ],
[ 'abandon', -2 ],
[ 'abduct', 1 ],
[ 'abduct', -2 ],
[ 'abduct', -2 ],
[ 'abhor', -3 ],
[ 'abhor', 1 ],
[ 'abhor', -1 ],
[ 'abil', 2 ],
[ 'abil', 4 ] ];


var arr2 = [ [ 'abandon' ],
[ 'abil' ],
[ 'abhor' ],
[ 'abduct' ],
['test'],
['hey'],
['testAgain'],
['array']];

var arr3 = [];

const mapping = arr2.map(word => {
    return word
})

for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){

    if(arr1[i][0] === mapping){
        arr3.push(Math.max(...arr1[i][1]))
    }

}
let arr4 = [...new Set(arr3)]

//example result:

var arr4 = [[abandon, -2],
[abduct, -2],
[abhor, -3],
[abil, 4]... and so on]
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, and I'm out of option. Need help.

Comment: your `arr2.map` for the mapping variable doesn't make sense, do you know what a map function does?

Comment: @Nard Pascua I think the expected output is wrong as `abandon` has `-2, 1, -2` and among them `1` is the largest. So please re-check your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can better use a `Set` instead of an array like `arr2` directly for finding a match as it will be constant time lookup in case of a `Set`.

Then use a `Array.prototype.filter` to filter the array `arr1` and get those arrays which are in `arr2`.

Lastly `Array.prototype.reduce` would help you make an object with the keys being the words and values being the largest value for that word in the `arr1` and you could use `Object.entries` from that object returned from `reduce` to get the data in the form of a 2-D array:

```js
var arr1 = [ [ 'abandon', -2 ],
[ 'abandon', 1 ],
[ 'abandon', -2 ],
[ 'abduct', 1 ],
[ 'abduct', -2 ],
[ 'abduct', -2 ],
[ 'abhor', -3 ],
[ 'abhor', 1 ],
[ 'abhor', -1 ],
[ 'abil', 2 ],
[ 'abil', 4 ] ];


var arr2 = [ [ 'abandon' ],
[ 'abil' ],
[ 'abhor' ],
[ 'abduct' ],
['test'],
['hey'],
['testAgain'],
['array']];

var lookup = new Set(arr2.flat());
var mapping = arr1.filter(([word, val]) => lookup.has(word));
var data = Object.entries(mapping.reduce((acc, o, i) => {
    if(acc[o[0]]){
        acc[o[0]] = Math.max(o[1], acc[o[0]]);
    }else{
        acc[o[0]] = o[1];
    }
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(data);
```

**EDIT**

Form your comment I assume that you are using a older version of node runtime where `flat()` is not present in the `Array.prototype`. So you can use the edited snippet below:

```js
var arr1 = [ [ 'abandon', -2 ],
[ 'abandon', 1 ],
[ 'abandon', -2 ],
[ 'abduct', 1 ],
[ 'abduct', -2 ],
[ 'abduct', -2 ],
[ 'abhor', -3 ],
[ 'abhor', 1 ],
[ 'abhor', -1 ],
[ 'abil', 2 ],
[ 'abil', 4 ] ];


var arr2 = [ [ 'abandon' ],
[ 'abil' ],
[ 'abhor' ],
[ 'abduct' ],
['test'],
['hey'],
['testAgain'],
['array']];

//flatten using Array.prototype.concat
var lookup = new Set([].concat.apply([], arr2)); 
//If Set doesn't work use the array, but this will not be a constant time lookup
//var lookup = [].concat.apply([], arr2);  

var mapping = arr1.filter(([word, val]) => lookup.has(word));
//If you are not using Set and going with an array, use Array.prototype.includes, so search won't be O(1)
//var mapping = arr1.filter(([word, val]) => lookup.includes(word));

var data = Object.entries(mapping.reduce((acc, o, i) => {
    if(acc[o[0]]){
        acc[o[0]] = Math.max(o[1], acc[o[0]]);
    }else{
        acc[o[0]] = o[1];
    }
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! will try it later.

Comment: I tried to run it on a browser and this actually works! However, I'm working on a nodeJS for this homework and it seems that ".flat()" and ".has" is not working for my nodeJS. But, I happen to find an alternative way for ".flat()". So, my only problem now is how can I refactor the "mapping". I tried "hasOwnProperty" and "includes" but they're not working. Please advise. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @LockandLock Please see the edit and comments in code, for the alternative solution using array.

Answer (score 0):

I would do with as few loops as possible.

```js
var arr1 = [ [ 'abandon', -2 ], [ 'abandon', 1 ], [ 'abandon', -2 ], [ 'abduct', 1 ], [ 'abduct', -2 ], [ 'abduct', -2 ], [ 'abhor', -3 ], [ 'abhor', 1 ], [ 'abhor', -1 ], [ 'abil', 2 ], [ 'abil', 4 ] ];

var arr2 = [ [ 'abandon' ], [ 'abil' ], [ 'abhor' ], [ 'abduct' ], ['test'], ['hey'], ['testAgain'], ['array']];


function getHighestResults(dataArr, filterArr) {
  var name = '';    // higher readability in code and created outside 
  var number = -1;  // for loops to avoid creating variables inside of them
  
  function existsInObject(obj, name) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(name);
  }
  
  function filterBasedOn(arr, obj) {
    var filteredArr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      name = arr[i][0];
      
      if (existsInObject(obj, name)) {
        filteredArr.push([name, obj[name]]);
      }
    }
    
    return filteredArr;
  }
  
  function getHighestValuesAsObj(arr) {
    var dataObj = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      name = arr[i][0];
      number = arr[i][1];
  
      if (!existsInObject(dataObj, name) || dataObj[name] < number) {
        dataObj[name] = number;
      }
    }
    
    return dataObj;
  }
    
  return filterBasedOn(filterArr, getHighestValuesAsObj(dataArr));
}


console.log(getHighestResults(arr1, arr2));
```